# ±100V supply for pulser application

Tags: dc, dc-dc-converter

I am currently implementing a pulser for an ultrasonic device.  I need to supply it with ±100V and a current of 0.5A.

My first approach was with two [NMT0572SCs](https://eu.mouser.com/datasheet/2/281/kdc_nmt-43471.pdf) (with ±72V) but I could not get them to work properly.

Now, my next option is to use the [MAX1771](https://datasheets.maximintegrated.com/en/ds/MAX1771.pdf), a usual suspect in boosting 12V at voltages above 100.

How can I invert the output? That is, how to get -100 volts?

Can it just be by inverting my +/- reference?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *My first approach was with two NMT0572SCs (with ±72V) but I could not
> get them to work properly.*

Those devices are only rated for 3 watts output power. You need 100 volts at 0.5 amps and that's an output power of 50 watts!!

> *My question is, how can I invert the output? that is, how to get -100
> volts. Can it just be by inverting my +/- reference?*

No, that won't work; you need a fundamentally different circuit to make an inverting boost converter and I would say your best option is to use a flyback converter. I'm suggesting this because the output is naturally galvanically isolated from the input and hence can be wired as a positive output voltage or a negative output voltage.

Answer (score 2):

To invert the supply to an ultrasonic transducer, drive it from a single 100VDC source, but use an [h-bridge](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/H-bridge). You do not need two supplies.

Reason being, the transducer just acts like a capacitor electrically, and doesn't require a truly negative supply. It only needs it's leads to be flipped, which is exactly what a h-bridge does.